# Installing Nim on windows 11

Tags: installation, nim-lang

I'm attempting to install nim onto Windows 11, but the virus protection is getting in the way. I've tried both from the main zip and choosenim. With the latter, I can sort of get it to download and ignore the virus scan using Admin run, but I then run into problems with it not finding the correct directories. (I think this might be related to me setting my default drive for some things to my D drive).

Comment: It's a recurrent problem (e.g. https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/9643#63598, https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/9388#61730). Some virus programmers use Nim to code them, so the Windows Antivirus thinks that some Nim features are also virus. It's a failure on the antivirus software.

Comment: Install a nightly build of nim, some of the syscalls that were getting flagged have been removed. But this is also not a question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try using scoop package manager to install `nim` in windows instead of downloading the regular `chooseNim` installer.

1. First install scoop from https://scoop.sh/
2. install `nim` using this command:  `scoop install nim`

Comment: There are many other package manager for windows. Is `scoop` more adapted to prevent this issue?